# Movable Side Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, move

`enter code here`I am currently trying to build a Webpage. On the left side is a small navbar with quicklinks. (Login and referral to a related blog etc).

Currently the navbar is static. But I would like to make it movable, so the user can drag and drop it to wherever he wants it to be.

My javascript knowledge istn't too good at the moment (working on it!), can someone help me create that effect?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){       
       var scroll_start = 0;
       var startchange = $('nav');
       var offset = startchange.offset();
       $(document).scroll(function() { 
          scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
          if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
              $('nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(51,51,51,0.8)');
           } else {
              $('nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(51,51,51,1)');
           }
       });
    });
    
    $('ul').draggable()
```

```css
/******************************************* MAIN */
    html {
     height: 100%;
    }
    body {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     height: 100%;
    }
    h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
     font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
     color:#333333;
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     font-weight:100;
     
    }
    h1 {
     font-family:'Khand',sans-serif;
     font-size:43px;
     font-weight:100;
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
    }
    h2 {
     font-family:'Khand',sans-serif;
     font-size:35px;
     font-weight:100;
     line-height:40px;
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
    }
    h3 {
     font-size:18px;
     line-height:25px;
    }
    p {
     font-size:18px;
     line-height:25px;
    }
    a {
     font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
     color:#db091a;
     text-decoration:none;
    }
    img {
     display:inline-block;
    }
    /************************************************************** BUTTON*/
    button.default {
     border-radius:0px;
     background:transparent;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 2px;
     border-color: #356651;
     color:#222;
     font-size:20px;
     font-family:'Khand',sans-serif;
     padding:5px 20px;
    }
    /*************************************** CLASSES */
    .container {
     width:80%;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    /*********************************** MAIN NAV*/
    nav{
     background:#333;
     top:0px;
     position:fixed;
     width:100%;
     height:50px;
     padding-top:20px;
     text-align:right;
     z-index:3;
    }
    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    nav li {
        display: inline;
        float: right;
    }
    nav li a {
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
        font-size:24px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3px 22px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    nav img {
     height:8px;
    }
    nav #menu-icon {
     color:#fff;
     font-size:30px;
     float:right;
     display:none;
    }
    
    /*MOBILE NAV*/
    @media only screen and (max-width : 700px) {
     nav #menu-icon {
      display:inline-block;
     }
     nav ul, nav:active ul { 
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      top: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #999;
     }
     nav:hover ul {
      display: block; 
     }
     nav li {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0px 0;
      margin: 0;
     }
    }
    
    /**********************************QUICKLINKS*/
    #quicklinks ul {
     list-style-type: none;
        margin: auto 0;
        padding: 0;
        position:fixed;
        top:50%;
        background:#db091a;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #333333;
    }
    #quicklinks ul li:not(.not) {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e45c4b;
    }
    #quicklinks ul img {
     display:block;
     padding: 10px 12px;
    }
    
    /*********************************CONTENT BOX 1*/
    #cb_1 {
     background-image: url("images/bg_2.jpg"); 
     height:100%;
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     z-index:-1;
    }
    #cb_1 h1 {
     color:#222;
     padding-top: 20px;
    }
    #cb_1 h3 {
     color:#356651;
    }
    #cb_1 p {
     color:#222;
     padding-top: 30px;
     padding-bottom:40px;
    }
    #cb_1 article {
     background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
     width:45%;
     padding:50px 50px;
     position:absolute;
     top:100px;
    }
    /*MOBILE BOX*/
    @media only screen and (max-width : 700px) {
     #cb_1 article {
     width:100%;
     }
    }
    /*********************************CONTENT BOX 2*/
    #cb_2 h1 {
     color:#333;
     padding-top: 20px;
     text-align:center;
    }
    #cb_2 h2 {
     color:#db091a;
     padding-top: 10px;
     text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     
     <title>This is a test</title>
     
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand" rel="stylesheet"> 
     
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <nav id="menu">
     <div class="container">
      <a href="#" id="menu-icon">&#9776;</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="images/pixel.png"> Lorem</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="images/pixel.png"> Ipsum</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="images/pixel.png"> Dolor</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="images/pixel.png"> Consetetur</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
    
    <aside id="quicklinks">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="Login" class="wrapper"><img src="glyphicon/user.png" ></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Tester" class="wrapper"><img src="glyphicon/user.png" ></a></li>
      <li class="not"><a href="#" title="Kontakt" class="wrapper"><img src="glyphicon/user.png" ></a></li>
     </ul>
    </aside>
    
    <section id="cb_1">
     <div class="container">
      <article>
       <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
       <h3>
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       </h3>
       <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       </p>
       <button type="button" class="default">Stet clita kasd</button> 
      </article>
     </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="cb_2">
     <div class="container">
      <article>
       <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
       <h2>
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       </h2>
      </article>
     </div>
    </section>
    
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr><td style="height:1000px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI. It'll need to be loaded along with jQuery. Then you can use `$('ul').draggable()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('nav');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
      $('nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(51,51,51,0.8)');
    } else {
      $('nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(51,51,51,1)');
    }
  });
  $('ul').draggable()

});
```

```css
/*************************************************************** MAIN */

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 43px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

a {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #db091a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
}


/************************************************************** BUTTON*/

button.default {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #356651;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}


/************************************************************ CLASSES */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/************************************************************ MAIN NAV*/

nav {
  background: #333;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 3;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav img {
  height: 8px;
}

nav #menu-icon {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  display: none;
}


/*MOBILE NAV*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  nav #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul,
  nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #999;
  }
  nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}


/***********************************************************QUICKLINKS*/

#quicklinks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  background: #db091a;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #333333;
  z-index: 100;
}

#quicklinks ul li:not(.not) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e45c4b;
}

#quicklinks ul img {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}


/********************************************************CONTENT BOX 1*/

#cb_1 {
  background-image: url("images/bg_2.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#cb_1 h1 {
  color: #222;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#cb_1 h3 {
  color: #356651;
}

#cb_1 p {
  color: #222;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#cb_1 article {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 45%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}


/*MOBILE BOX*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #cb_1 article {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/********************************************************CONTENT BOX 2*/

#cb_2 h1 {
  color: #333;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#cb_2 h2 {
  color: #db091a;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <nav id="menu">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" id="menu-icon">&#9776;</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/pixel.png"> Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/pixel.png"> Ipsum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/pixel.png"> Dolor</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="images/pixel.png"> Consetetur</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <aside id="quicklinks">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" title="Login" class="wrapper"><img src="glyphicon/user.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" title="Tester" class="wrapper"><img src="glyphicon/user.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="not">
        <a href="#" title="Kontakt" class="wrapper"><img src="glyphicon/user.png"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>

  <section id="cb_1">
    <div class="container">
      <article>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <h3>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
          sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <button type="button" class="default">Stet clita kasd</button>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="cb_2">
    <div class="container">
      <article>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <h2>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </h2>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:1000px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: And you made sure to add jQuery UI as well as jQuery to your Webpage?

Comment: yes, I added it. When dragging I see a "ghosty" version of the navbar, but it stays fixed to the position. I already tried to change the CSS, but still didn't work :/

Comment: Hmm... It's hard to say without seeing if anything else is affecting it. Was able to get it to work in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/WEbNbQ) as well.

Comment: I added more of my code. Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to put the HTML/CSS/JS in their own boxes. Hope you can still read it

Comment: In your css  add `z-index: 100` to `#quicklinks ul`.